# WPF Application designed in VS 2012 won't run on Windows 7 machine

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7, visual-studio-2012, clickonce

I've designed a WPF C# application using Visual Studio 2012. The application, which is simple enough, runs fine on my **Windows 8** machine using the `ClickOnce` deployment method. The datagrid displays the content from a SQL Server database and performs all of it's other functions just as I've designed it to, but when I attempt to install it on a Windows 7 machine it immediately crashes and I'm not sure why.
 The Windows 7 computer I'm trying to install the application on has .NET 4.5 running on it, but is there anything else that computer needs to have installed on it in order to run applications developed with VS 2012. 
This is my first attempt to install an application developed with VS 2012 on a Windows 7 machine, so I'm not sure if there's another step that I'm missing here. Any help you guys can provide would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Is there any kind of Message or Exeption?

Comment: Yeah, ok - so that is where "doing your job" comes into play. Checking event logs for errors, all the stuff you are now, in your first programming work as a trainee, are learning. SERIOUSLY - you expect us to pull out the magic ball and get this out? At least show more than 10 seconds thought. What have you tried to find out? Event log would be my first start.

Comment: I presume the .NET Framework 4.5 redistriburable is installed on your Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Hey Venson, the only message that pops up simply tells me that the application has stopped working and that if Microsoft has a solution it will tell show it once the application is closed down (I'm paraphrasing that because I don't currently have access to the computer I was installing the application on).

Comment: TomTom I agree with you that your job isnt to do my work for me and I apologize if you thought that was what I was asking of you. As I stated above I dont have access to the Windows 7 machine and wont again until Monday at which point I will check the event log like suggested. My hope in posting this question was that if someone here remembers an article where a similar problem was encountered that I missed in my web search (I admit it wasnt exhaustive and Ill search more once I get out of work) that someone could point me to it because I do not have an issue with doing the learning on my own.

Answer (score 0):

The message you stated "The application has stopped working and that if Microsoft has a solution..." is an indicator of one of the following:

- The Framework is disabled; though 4.5 is installed several root instances are built on the foundation which are apart of Framework 2.0.  This particular Framework can cause issues for 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, and even 4.5.
- The `System.EnterpriseServices.dll` is damaged in the Framework. Which needs to be connected back to the Global Assembly Cache (GAC).
- And another common issue is the `machine.config` file log in the Framework Folder can be corrupt and needs to be replaced with a valid one.

There are others that can occur within the System Policy Folder as well, which may require you to use the .Net Cleanup Tool and reinstall the Framework.  But before you do any troubleshooting you should go to the Event Viewer and get details of what is going on.

---

Try these steps first for me:

1. Windows Key + R
2. When the run prompt appears type: `appwiz.cpl`
3. Go to the left hand side: **Turn Windows Features On or Off**
4. Turn Framework 3.5 on if it isn't already; if it is already on go to Step 5.
5. Turn off the Framework; then reboot.
6. Once rebooted follow steps 1-4 again.

Now at this point I would suggest trying the application again.  If it fails try this:

1. Open Start
2. Type 'cmd' in Search
3. Right Click and Run as an Administrator
4. Type `%windir%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.0.50727\ngen.exe update`
5. Then type: `sfc /scannow`

The Native Regeneration tool will try to repair the Framework back to a factory state; the System-File-Checker will attempt to fix any errors indicated in Windows.  If it can't it will say 'it found integrity violations'.

Those are the steps I would do for general support; but you really should try and locate an error message.  As the Framework can become a huge ordeal to cleanup and fix.  If you provide more information I will revise my response to help address it.

Hopefully that helps.